# Python OpenSSL "WantWriteError" when trying to transfer a JSON of more than 64kb in size through https from Windows 7 and Windows server 2016

Tags: python-3.x, windows, sockets, python-requests, pyopenssl

I have a python server client implementation using the following packages - **Cherrypy, PyOpenSSL, requests**. The response to a certain requests.post is JSON data of size more than 64kb. The server is a **Windows Server 2016** and client is a **Windows 7/10**. When I try the same request in **http** over **port 80** the entire data is transferred whereas if I do the same over **https** on **port 443**, only 64kb of the data is transferred and the transfer is terminated without any error. The response code is 200 OK, even though the entire JSON is not transferred.

Whereas if the server is **Windows 10**, the entire data is transferred over both https and http. I am running python 3.7. The above behavior is observed after migrating to python 3.7 from python 2.7. The error thrown at the PyOpenSSL level is "***WantWriteError***", which indicates a socket buffer overload, I am not sure how to tackle this problem and what is different between the OS. I appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in Cheroot, see https://github.com/cherrypy/cheroot/issues/245

You can find some potential workarounds there that you can try until this is fixed. Also, you can try using the `builtin` TLS adapter instead of `pyopenssl`.